# Showing ads in the specific category and its sub-categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like in each category and **sub-category** of its own ads to be displayed.
I used the in_category function but not displayed Advertising in sub-categories.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear. As I understood you need to display different advertiesments on each category page. If I got it right here is your answer,

First create a custom field for categories. you can use Advanced Custom Fields plugin for that.and then copy your add code in to that field. echo that field on your category.php file. It'll work

Comment: I want in WordPress by using the in_category function in my categories showing various advertising. Note: The categories and their sub-categories.